# Антоним к "жертва [обстоятельств]"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, антонимы, идиомы

В разных источниках в качестве антонимов к слову "жертва" приводятся "хищник", "охотник", "убийца", по противоположным сторонам ситуации "кто кого убил". Я же ищу антоним к слову "жертва" совсем другого характера.

В выражении "жертва обстоятельств" (или катастрофы, например) слово "жертва" используется как указание на то, что субъект **пострадал** от чего-то (обстоятельств), **попал в неблагоприятную ситуацию**.

**Я ищу слово, которое означало бы нечто обратное:** субъекта, которому нечто **принесло пользу** или которого **привело к благоприятной ситуации**.

А если есть выбор (мало ли!), то в идеале с негативным оттенком. Скажем, в контексте, когда человек оказался в нужном месте в нужное время и занял престижный пост, которым доволен, но с которым справляется плохо и приносит скорее вред, чем пользу. Он "... обстоятельств", благодаря обстоятельствам он попал в прекрасную (для него) ситуацию и пользуется ею во вред другим. Ничего за душой не имеющий, кроме этого внезапного везения в прошлом, что позволило бы ему в такую ситуацию попасть.

Если выбора толком нет, то просто антоним выражению "жертва обстоятельств" (необязательно со словом "обстоятельств"), тоже подойдёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, "баловень судьбы", "любимчик судьбы", "счастливчик","везунчик", "фаворит"? Это из  того контекста, который я поняла.

Comment: Во, точно, *"баловень судьбы"* я никак не мог вспомнить. Спасибо. Подожду ещё вариантов, но этот пока выглядит лучшим.

Answer (score 1):

возможно антонимом к слову "жертва"является "кровопийца"?

Comment: Нет, я ищу антоним не к отдельному слову, а всему выражению. "Кровопийца обстоятельств" звучит странновато. Впрочем, не сказать чтобы совсем бессмысленно.

Comment: Так, спустя год я уже собственный вопрос забыл, извините %) Да, под сформулированные требования слово действительно подходит.

Answer (score 1):

**А если есть выбор (мало ли!), то в идеале с негативным оттенком. Скажем, в контексте, когда человек оказался в нужном месте в нужное время и занял престижный пост, которым доволен, но с которым справляется плохо и приносит скорее вред, чем пользу. Он "... обстоятельств"...**

В определённом контексте / стиле можно в качестве метафоры использовать выражение "**бенефициар ситуации** (обстоятельств)". Нередко слово "бенефициар" носит негативный оттенок, да и выражение "бенефициар ситуации" встречается. Поэтому я полагаю, что такую метафору вполне можно удачно использовать.

Comment: Это больше "получающий" выгоду (пассивно), нежели "извлекающий" её (активно), но в вопросе я это упустил, да и это довольно тонкое отличие, для контекста всё равно более-менее подходит. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может, победитель, хозяин положения(ситуации),  властитель судьбы?

Comment: Нет, не подходит. Именно извлекающий выгоду из случайного благоприятного стечения обстоятельств ранее, не комплимент, мол, кроме везения в прошлом ничего за душой не имеющий. Хм... вообще это стоит добавить в вопрос, я это закладывал в "негативный оттенок", но явно стоит развернуть эту мысль подробнее. Впрочем, негативный оттенок это только опция, за варианты в любом случае спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

рожденный под счастливой звездой
автор своей жизни
певец своего счастья
повелитель судеб
центр Вселенной
любимец Фортуны

управляющий обстоятельствами
поборовший обстоятельства
переступивший, перешагнувший через обстоятельства
рулевой обстоятельств

Comment: Немного не туда, нет. Я ищу не комплимент, а скорее наоборот, нечто почти унизительное. С акцентом не на том, что некто сумел преодолеть обстоятельства, а на том, что без удачи преодолеть их не может. Хотя некоторые варианты частично подходят. Спасибо.